# error in grep using a regex expression

Tags: regex, grep

I think I have uncovered an error in grep. If I run this grep statement against a db log on the command line it runs fine.

```
grep "Query Executed in [[:digit:]]\{5\}.\?" db.log
```

I get this result:

> Query Executed in 19699.188 ms;"select distinct * from /xyztable.....

when I run it in a script

```
LONG_QUERY=`grep "Query Executed in [[:digit:]]\{5\}.\?" db.log`
```

the asterisk in the result is replaced with a list of all files in the current directory.

```
echo $LONG_QUERY
```

Result:

> Query Executed in 19699.188 ms; "select distinct `<list of files in
>   current directory>` from /xyztable.....

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: when I posted this the second result should have been select distinct file file2 file3 from /xyztable.... I had put the files in bracket and when I posted the question it seemed to remove everything in the brackets.

Comment: Edit your post then

Comment: It's [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html), very expected and can be suppressed by quoting: `echo "$LONG_QUERY"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error in grep. This is an error in your understanding of how scripts are interpreted.

If I write in a script:

```
echo *
```

I will get a list of filenames, because an unquoted, unescaped, asterisk is interpreted by the shell (not grep, but /bin/bash or /bin/sh or whatever shell you use) as a request to substitute filenames matching the pattern '*', which is to say all of them.

If I write in a script:

```
echo "*"
```

I will get a single '*', because it was in a quoted string.

If I write:

```
STAR="*"
echo $STAR
```

I will get filenames again, because I quoted the star while assigning it to a variable, but then when I substituted the variable into the command it became unquoted.

If I write:

```
STAR="*"
echo "$STAR"
```

I will get a single star, because double-quotes allow variable interpolation.

You are using backquotes - that is, ` characters - around a command. That captures the output of the command into a variable.

I would suggest that if you are going to be echoing the results of the command, and little else, you should just redirect the results into a file. (After all, what are you going to do when your LONG_QUERY contains 10,000 lines of output because your log file got really full?)

Barring that, at the very least do `echo "$LONG_QUERY"` (in double quotes).